# Manipulating State with Local Variable Inside createSlice Reducers

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

The screenshot below is taken from the Maximilian Schwarzmüller's Udemy Course "React - The Complete Guide (incl Hooks, React Router, Redux)"

In the "else" portion of the `addItemToCart` reducer, Max manipulates `existingItem.quantity` and `existingItem.totalPrice` to `existingItem`, which seems to simply be a local variable that was created from inside the reducer. Whereas in other cases he had to make changes directly to the state, such as in the "if" portion where he pushes an item to the state. Why does incrementing `existingItem` actually work to increment inside the state itself?

[image]

**UPDATE: code in text below:**

```
    import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'cart',
  initialState: {
    items: [],
    totalQuantity: 0,
  },
  reducers: {
    addItemToCart(state, action) {
      const newItem = action.payload;
      const existingItem = state.items.find((item) => item.id === newItem.id);
      state.totalQuantity++;
      if (!existingItem) {
        state.items.push({
          id: newItem.id,
          price: newItem.price,
          quantity: 1,
          totalPrice: newItem.price,
          name: newItem.title
        });
      } else {
        existingItem.quantity++;
        existingItem.totalPrice = existingItem.totalPrice + newItem.price;
      }
    },
    removeItemFromCart(state, action) {
      const id = action.payload;
      const existingItem = state.items.find(item => item.id === id);
      state.totalQuantity--;
      if (existingItem.quantity === 1) {
        state.items = state.items.filter(item => item.id !== id);
      } else {
        existingItem.quantity--;
      }
    },
  },
});

export const cartActions = cartSlice.actions;

export default cartSlice;
```

Comment: Please provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Post code as plain text instead of screenshots

Comment: @slideshowp2 good point: added file text above